# GIT - Ignore eclipse resources

Tags: eclipse, git, ignore

git status keeps on showing eclipse resources:

```
naaka@naaka-ux501:~/dev/workspaces/ebeans$ git status

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'watour/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working    directory)

modified:   .gitignore
modified:   .gitignore~
modified:   .metadata/.log
deleted:    .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/services/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat
modified:       modified:   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/externalLibsTimeStamps
modified:   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus/05b0fe8524860bd73cbb07ef30fb34cc/segments.gen
modified:   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus/830bc118332e77292949ed1e6d2fabe0/segments.gen
modified:   .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus/fded8792ea35992e87221e67a8dea03d/segments.gen
modified:   .metadata/version.ini
```

i tried several versions of gitignore:

```
/target/
/log/
**/.project
**/.classpath
**/.metadata
**/.settings
**/.recommenders
/.project
/.classpath
/.metadata
/.settings
/.recommenders
/.gitignore~
.metadata
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath
.recommenders
```

I also tried removing cached data and committing

```
git rm --cached .metadata
```

but they keep coming back!

Comment: You are doing this from command line, so this has in fact nothing to do with Eclipse at all. Just a .gitignore problem. My guess is that the `/` is making those absolute paths. Will test...

Comment: BTW, where does the .project file lie relatively to the .gitignore?

Comment: Also, it says that `.metadata` is _modified_, so it is already under version control. I don't think that .gitignore will have any effect then. Remove it from version control first.

Answer (score 1):

You have already added `.metadata` folder to version control that's why it says modified

```
modified:   .metadata/.log
```

you need to remove it from version control (git) and then add it to `.gitignore`

```
rm -rf .metadata
git add .
git commit -m "Remove .metadata from version control"
```

Then add .metadata to `.gitignore`

```
# gitignore

.metadata/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the cache of `.gitignore` file too. Try with 
`git rm --cached .gitignore`